# 3d surface mesh triangulation

Tags: opengl, graphics, triangulation

Does anyone know an algorithm to generate a 3d surface mesh given a set of vertices? My project requires that we construct an irregular 3d object  in OpenGL and I am having trouble finding out how to do this using triangulation.

Comment: "generate a 3d surface mesh given a set of vertices"...like a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Higher_dimensions)?

Answer (score 0):

You better with a library like cgal. It implements the boywer-watson algorithm but with tetrahedrons. It's a very fast incremental triangulation. Then find the convex hull and remove edges exceeding alpha.